# MAMP: reloading pages is very slow

Tags: php, localhost, mamp

On a basic installation of **MAMP**, I'm building an application with CodeIgniter locally (MacBook Pro, Core2Duo 2,26 GhZ, 4GB RAM).

My problem is, that when I reload a page, it does **load very slow**, even slower than when I put on a web server.

It's strange that it only loads slow when I reload the page, not when I click on a link in the application itself.

The application uses a MySQL database, but even when I reload a page that doesn't make MySQL queries, it's so slow, that it takes about 10 seconds to load a page.

I read on http://forum.mamp.info/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=14081 that I could try to change the server name from .local to .dev. But I don't know how to do that and didn't find anything when I googled it.

What could I do about it?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The '.local' domains conflict with Bonjour, which treats anything with a '.local' TLD as a Bonjour server.

I found the answer here: http://www.bram.us/2011/12/12/mamp-pro-slow-name-resolving-with-local-vhosts-in-lion-fix/, and that post refers to https://discussions.apple.com/message/15834652#15834652.

The solution is to, as Jon said, put a `::1` address in/etc/hosts.

```
::1 localhost   example.local    anotherexample.local
```

Unfortunately, MAMP Pro will delete the entry when it restarts **so put a tab (not spaces) between the IP and each of the hosts**.

The alternative is to put a different TLD - `.dev` or something like that.

Comment: may I ask why your dev installs end with .local?
default MAMP sites are like this:
http://localhost:8888/your_site

Comment: @beda69 In my case it was because I was working in an agency that 200 or so websites and everybody else used .local TLDs. File paths were relative to root. I use Vagrant and Gas Mask now.

Comment: This seems to have fixed my issue, though mine was slightly different. I used .dev for my local domains. This worked fine for 99% of the time, but whenever I connected to 'The Cloud' public free WIFI, it tanked and went very slow. Making an entry this way as you describe solved the issue. Really weird!

Comment: use .localhost it was made for that.

Answer (score 19):

To solve the problem with .local domains on OSX, do the following (assuming your site is called mysite.local):

1. Open your `/etc/hosts` file in a text editor
2. Add the following entry on its own line `::1 mysite.local`
3. Save the file

This should resolve your issue.

Comment: This is it. Now it's as fast as it should be. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What does that do? Is that supposed to be some wildcard? I thought that wasn't possible on OSX..

Comment: OSX 10.7 uses [Multicast DNS](http://www.multicastdns.org) for Bonjour which has the .local TLD reserved.  Adding this hosts entry defines the domain for IPv6 which causes OSX to skip the Bonjour lookup (which times out, creating the speed issue).

Comment: Ok, after working some hours with the new hosts settings, it's again very slow. I also tried xampp, which, however, showed up with the same poor performance. I'm now developing online, which is much faster, but I think that's quite paradox... Do you maybe know another solution how to get it working as fast as it should on OSX 10.7?

Comment: @Purr does it work better if you use something else then .local?

Comment: This also seemed to fix a slowness issue i was having with mysite.dev

Comment: @Mattias Wadman: No, it doesn't really work better. It tried it with mamp.dev and I'm sure that I correctly applied the recommended settings for the hosts file.

Comment: Ok, I flushed DNS cache with `dscacheutil -flushcache` and now it seems to work... for now. I will test it for some more time to see if that's what solved the problem,

Comment: My MAMP resolves to localhost:8888 and adding localhost:8888 doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas? Really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If on OS X Yosemite. The edit to the localhost file will not fix it. You will need to do the following.

sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.discoveryd.plist 
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.discoveryd.plist

The fix is via https://coderwall.com/p/ylchfq. Update is in the comments.

Comment: "/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.discoveryd.plist: No such file or directory"

Comment: the file does not exist in El Capitan, 10.11.3