# Mamp localhost resolving very slowly

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mamp, hosts

When I make local changes to my PHP / WordPress website, the localhost does not seem to update for 20-30 minutes.

I'm on Mac OSX 10.8.4 and using MAMP Pro. I have two sites that I have created separate host entries for, let's call them `mysite1.dev` and `mysite2.dev`.

Here is my MAMP Server configuration:

```
Apache: 80
MySQL: 3306
SSL: 443
```

I saw this article ( [How can I eliminate slow resolving/loading of localhost/virtualhost (a 2-3 second lag) on Mac OS X Lion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064581/how-can-i-eliminate-slow-resolving-loading-of-localhost-virtualhost-a-2-3-secon) ) on the Bonjour conflicts and edited my `/private/etc/hosts` file with the suggestions in this article:

1. I changed the host names from `mysite1.localhost` to `mysite.dev` because it sounds like the conflict is with `.local` names - DID NOT WORK
2. I updated the Hosts file to have separate `::1` addresses - DID NOT WORK:

   ```
   ::1 <tab> mysite1.dev
   ::1 <tab> mysite2.dev
   ```
3. I tried putting all of my host entries onto one line - also didn't work:

   ```
   127.0.0.1 localhost mysite1.dev mysite2.dev
   ::1 localhost
   fe80::1%lo0 localhost
   ```

It seems like MAMP Pro overwrites the hosts file any time I restart the server.

I would be SUPER grateful for any help you can offer.

Comment: Im not sure if this will help, but its a suggestion :-)   Try and clear all cache you can find attached to your browser.  Also try to totally reinstall your MAMP server.  Remember to take backup.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452614/mamp-reloading-pages-is-very-slow

found this aswell.. check it out.. idk if it helps, if it does im happy :-)

Comment: This sounds like a WordPress caching issue, not a database thing. Have you looked in the WordPress database to see if the content changes have applied? Next step: Turn off plugins to isolate the problem.

Comment: After upgrading php to 5.5 in MAMP, for some obscure reason, OPCache is enabled by default. This makes the server return cached versions of pages instead of the newer versions (with your changes). I followed [instructions from this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19130992/1200166) to disable OPCache.

Answer (score 17):

Change MAMP cache to OPcache. It worked for me [image]

Comment: Using OPcache during development is no good idea. Normally you disable all caching during development. Otherwise you have to wait ages until your latest changes are reflected on the site.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and found the solution on this post:  [MAMP time between seeing live changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19079089/mamp-time-between-seeing-live-changes/19268769#19268769)

The instructions, which I followed:

The solution is uncommenting lines in the `php.ini` file, which can be found in

```
/{MAMP Directory}/bin/php/php5.5.3/conf/php.ini
```

Comment out Opcache:

```
[OPcache]
;zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/opcache.so"
;  opcache.memory_consumption=128
;  opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8
;  opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000
;  opcache.revalidate_freq=60
;  opcache.fast_shutdown=1
;  opcache.enable_cli=1
```

Documentation ( yes it started in 5.5 ):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.opcache.php

Comment: Using OPcache during development is actually no good idea. While your site may load a little bit faster you have to hit reload much more often until you see the current changes you made.

Answer (score 4):

I've been struggling with this issue ever since switching to SSL for my local environment (thanks, Salesforce API) and finally found a solution that worked for me:

[image: Disable Xdebug]

Turning off Xdebug cut TTFB from 25 seconds to 2. Yeesh.

Comment: For those of you looking, this is found under the 'PHP' tab on the left hand side of the screen

Comment: Thanks! In my case, there were no responses at all. Disabling PHP Debug Listening in my PHPStorm fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problems running php 5.5.3. After I changed back to `5.4.19` it worked.

You can change the version in the `MAMP GUI`. You might have to rename your `5.5.3` folder to `5.5.X` for `5.4.19` to show up in the GUI. The `php` folders are placed at: `Applications/MAMP/bin/php`

Answer (score 3):

For me, changing back to MAMPS standard port settings did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

I was having same issue, I had added virtual host ending with `.local` which was causing 5 seconds delay in lookup.

To fix this I updated host file.

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

And added my site with IPv6 address along with `::1` and `127.0.0.1`.

```
::1             mysite.local
127.0.0.1       mysite.local
fe80::1%lo0     mysite.local
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution that worked for me was to turn off Xdebug as @tammy-shipps mentioned. However since I have the vanilla MAMP version, I had to turn off Xdebug with the `php.ini` file found here:

`/{MAMP Directory}/bin/php/{PHP Version}/conf/php.ini`

Then change `xdebug.remote_enable` from 1 to 0:

`xdebug.remote_enable=0`

Unlike other proposed solutions, turning off cache or changing ports had no affect on the problem.

Comment: Already disabled in my php.ini. Still very slow server.

Comment: Thank you!!! I have been dealing with painfully slow MAMP Pro for years — randomly changing settings trying to find anything that helps. This did the trick! Much faster. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

MAMP's default ports are non-standard.  When I switched to standard ports (80 for Apache & 443 for SSL), it sped up dramatically.

I'm not sure if this is what Paul Bakker did, or if he switched the other way.

I'm using MAMP Pro 4.2, PHP 7.1.6, Apache, OS X 10.11.6.

Answer (score 1):

It was really hard, but I found a solution that it works in my environment:

- MAMP 4.2.1
- PHP 5.6.31

SETTINGS left menu > Ports settings > Run servers as: > Change it to "Unix Users" option.

[image]

Comment: I did this and now when I browse to any page it says "... isn't writable by PHP. Please fix that." What else did you do if anything?

Comment: Hey @StevenThate. I didn't do anything else but it seems a permission problem. 
Since the answer is one year old, I would look for the isolated error since it is possible you're using a new Mac OS or MAMP version. By the way, it seems a permission error, try to reset permissions on your site.

Comment: Thanks. Turns out updating MAMP from 5.1 to 5.4 fixed my performance issues.

Comment: I'm on Mac Big Sur, and I tried this, and while the pages load fast, they fail due to Apache not having permission to write to a log file specified by the PHP code. Since I work with many repos that I mostly didn't write, I don't care to go down this rabbit hole, so I'm switching back until I find a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Setting xdebug.remote_host to to 127.0.0.1 instead of "localhost" solved this issue for me. This skips IPV6 resolution, which caused the delay.

Switching off remote_enable is not an option, because it kills debugging in PHPStorm:

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
```

Comment: This worked! (Or disabling entirely as suggested by Frank). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Mamp, however, I use `php -S 0.0.0.0:4444` to spin up a local server. Its response got very slow after moving to Mojave.

I was able to fix it by updating `/etc/hosts` file with

```
::1             localhost YouMacName.local
127.0.0.1       localhost YouMacName.local
```

You can get YourMacName.local by running in terminal:

```
$ hostname
```

Answer (score 0):

**Switch off** the
**PHP-Cache**
as shown below screenshot.

[image]
[Below in the screen shot you can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cppWI.png)