# MAMP running extremely slow with external database connection

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mamp

I am dealing with really slow loading of pages. I used Chrome console's Network tab to get this information (but it is slow on all browsers).

I have researched the issue heavily, but now I am completely stumped. I have tried [**Blowski's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10041204/1893629) to *MAMP: reloading pages is very slow* (editing my `hosts` file), but had no luck with getting the page to load faster.

I am running OS X 10.8.5, CodeIgniter 2.1.3, and connecting to a remote MySQL database (which is on the same server as the live web server). Not sure if that has anything to do with the waiting being so long. Speed tests for loading the same page are below:

**localhost**
Waiting time is 13.49 seconds

[image]

**Web Server**
Waiting time is 222 milliseconds

[image]

What can I do to fix this issue?

**Update:** I've narrowed down the issue to the MySQL database (which is located on a remote server, separate from where PHP (MAMP) is installed). Are there any settings I would need to change to fix this horrible load time? I am also connecting to the database using an IP address and not a domain name, so I don't believe it is a DNS issue with the server MySQL is installed on.

Comment: What does "10 minutes away" mean in terms of the connection?  Are the PHP and MySQL machines in the same data center?

Comment: I just mean that the MySQL server is close. It's not on the other side of the country. PHP and MySQL are in the same data center only on web server, not on localhost.

Comment: For the purposes of this question, PHP is running on your local machine, connecting to a MySQL database at a remote location -- correct?  What kind of connection is there between these applications?  That is why you are running slow.  For every page request there may be dozens of *sequential* round trips as data moves back and forth between PHP and MySQL.  The solution would be to run a local copy of MySQL or somehow reduce the network congestion between your data and applications layers.

Comment: You are correct. I understand your suggestion, but what doesn't make sense to me is why is this happening only locally? I have a website running a MySQL database on a web server and it is running fine and have done with many times before running PHP/MySQL on different servers. Is there something different about "local" PHP?

Comment: No I did not. I ended up using a different computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a general solution, try using a profiler - it is meant for diagnosing performance issues.

this link has a pretty good tutorial - http://geek.michaelgrace.org/2011/08/xdebug-cachegrind-and-mamp-on-mac-osx/

You should examine the results to see which function(s) take the most time of execution. I suspect your remote database connection may be at fault, but a profiler will give you definitive results.

Comment: This didn't answer my question, but I am accepting it because it helped lead me to the source of the issue (which is still not solved) It boils down to long waiting for MySQL connections/queries.

Answer (score 0):

Such a long lag makes me suspect profiling as the culprit, especially since it's only on localhost.

Check your php.ini if `xdebug` is enabled (it may be found in a separate `xdebug.ini`), and if so, if `xdebug.profiler_enable` is set to true/1.

That, or perhaps MAMP uses another profiler.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried adding it in my master php.ini and local php.ini as well as using `ini_set` but no luck in fixing the issue :(

Comment: I didn't meant to set it to true (thus enabling it), I meant that if it was present, that could be the cause of the lag. Perhaps you could try setting it to false instead?

Comment: Oh I see. Well by default it was off, I manually set it to false though but still not working.

Comment: I've updated the question. Figured out it is my connection to the remote MySQL database... not sure if you have any other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the server running the MySQL daemon is configured to do reverse DNS lookups? With the development machine being your own computer on a standard ISP line this could cause a serious delay on each request, as the reverse DNS lookup has to time out every time.

Comment: I would I change the configuration to not do this?

Comment: This is a setting your MySQL server's admin has to set. You might be out of luck on shared and/or managed hosting though. Having the same situation here.

Comment: I have root access and MySQL admin access

Comment: To turn off MySQL reverse DNS Lookups: edit your  mysql config file (my.ini my.cnf or whatever)  

in the [mysqld] section add

# Skip reverse DNS lookup of clients

skip-name-resolve