# MAMP: refresh the server very slowly

Tags: php, macos, apache, mamp

I have started php programming on mac i am using MAMP in my mac os 10.9.

But there is a problem about the MAMP, it shows my changes in localhost very late. I have to wait 15-20 seconds for see the changes.

I have googled it, there is a good solution on the stackoverflow:

[MAMP: reloading pages is very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452614/mamp-reloading-pages-is-very-slow)

The solution is:

> Open your /etc/hosts file in a text editor
>
> Add the following entry on its own line ::1 mysite.local
>
> Save the file

And my question is what is the **mysite** part of this command? I am sure that, I have to change it. But I don't know what will be there..

Please help.

Cheers!

Comment: The my site part is the virtual host your are using (i.e. apiserver.local). If you are using none this method does not apply to you. Furthermore i would rather discourage using .local to avoid any kind of conflict.

Comment: I try to change PHP version, than now it is working normal. So I am using PHP 5.2.17.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem. It was about my PHP version, I don't know why but when I've change my php version from MAMP settings it started to work normally.